# Не открывается экшен в контроллере при включённом UrlManager

Tags: php, yii2

Есть контроллер Back, в нём находится экшен Admin.

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller

class BackController extends Controller {
     public function actionAdmin(){
        return 'admin';
    }
}
```

Без использования UrlManager, переходя по
site.org/index.php?r=back/admin

всё работает.
А при включенном UrlManager, переходя по site.org/back/admin у меня вылазит ошибка 404.

UrlManager:

```
'urlManager' => [
 ...
    'rules' => [
        '' => 'site/index',
        '<action>' => 'site/<action>'
    ],
],
```

P.S. сильно не бейте :D

Comment: НЕ АТУАЛЬНО, я понял в чём была моя ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

В urlManager нужно добавить 'enablePrettyUrl' => true

Comment: 'enablePrettyUrl' => true стоит и так, это ничего не меняет.